# How to Download database from hosting server plesk-web13

Tags: sql-server, database, web-hosting, plesk

I have a database on A plesk web hosting server, and I'd like to download it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: follow this link: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/plesk/how-to-backup-a-database-plesk

Comment: I am using myLittleAdmin (for SQL Server and MSDE) v.2.0 lite r.096 this features dons't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download database via domain's backup. Here the example for Plesk 12:

[image: plesk backup database]

[image: plesk download database]

Comment: And how to attach that backup as database

Comment: @khaled Could you please describe your full case? Are you just want to create database backup? Or you want to move to another Plesk? Or you want to move to another non-plesk shared hosting? Or you want to move to own VPS/VDS? In any case file you are downloaded is a native MSSQL database file and can be attached with mssql import tools.

Comment: Thank you , I have got it , I just didn't know that I could download backup file and attache it as database and I have got it